# Unsupported class file major version 61 for gradle's bootJar task

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

i've just upgraded java in my project to 17 version. When i'm trying to build it with gradle i'm facing this error

```
Execution failed for task ':project:bootJar'.
> Error while evaluating property 'mainClassName' of task ':project:bootJar'
   > Unsupported class file major version 61
```

So , my main java conventions config has

```
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
```

Also i set proper sdk to gradle config in IDEA, Gradle wrapper upgraded to 7.4

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Are you running the task through an  IDE like IntelliJ or from the command line?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson , 2.3.*

Comment: @akortex , from command line

Comment: Have you verified that the java version you are running is indeed the correct one? Maybe either you system is not configured correctly or Gradle is picking up some other Java version. What is the output of the `./gradlew --version` command?

Comment: Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17 (Oracle Corporation 17+35-2724)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.3.1 x86_64

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.3 is not compatible with Java 17. Spring Boot 2.4 was the first version that is Java 17 compatible but it is [no longer supported](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support). At the time of writing, the supported versions of Spring Boot that are compatible with Java 17 are 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: upgrading spring to Java 17 compatible version helped! Thank you so much!

Comment: I updated also `org.springframework.boot` plugin to the spring boot version. That helped.